# Исключение при открытии XAML Designer

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

Похоже случайно внесла изменения во внутренние настройки Visual Studio. Теперь вместо окна отображает только это. An Exception was thrown[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Прошу, помогите исправить! Удалять и заново устанавливать студию нет времени(

Comment: А при каких обстоятельствах это показывается?

Comment: когда пытаюсь открыть Design, код XAML показывает, само окно нет(((

Comment: А, хорошо. А если в другом проекте попробовать?

Comment: все равно,не помогает

Comment: В другом проекте то же самое?

Comment: в других проектах где показывает только границы окна, самого окна не видно, а где-то точно так же

Comment: И такое же сообщение?

Comment: да, точно такое же сообщение

Comment: в другом проекте обычную Form отображает, XAML нет